# How to replace the "-" with the guessed letters?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a hangman game with String methods, however, I am having trouble replacing the "-" with the correct letter guessed, the specifications on my problem says that I need to concatenate the dashes with the letters that were guessed correctly.

this is the code I have so far for the method that checks if the letter is in the word

```
public static String reveal(String word, String guess) 
    {
        String dashprints = "-", wholeword=" ";
        for (int index=0; index<= word.length();index++)
        {
            if(index==word.indexOf(letters))
            {
                return dashprints;
            }
            else
            {
                dashprints=letters;
            }
            wholeword= dashprints+ wholeword;

        }
            return wholeword;
```

The word in the game is:
graphics

and the initial output is this:

"---------"

and the wanted output is:

"g-------"

however, the output I am getting right now is just this:

"-"

Comment: `index<= word.length();` is going to cause a problem. And if the index is ever where it needs to be, you just return `-`, which isn't what you want

Comment: [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The title of your question is 'How to replace the "-" with the guessed letters?' but then you say initial output is --- desired output is g-------. Do you want initial output(before any guess) to be g-- or after user inputs g? Have you declared letters?

Comment: what is value of letters?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
public static String reveal(String word, String guess) {
    char[] guessChars = guess.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> missedChars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    char[] out = new char[word.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = '_';
    }
    if (word.length() == guess.length()) {
        for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
            int sts = word.indexOf(guessChars[index]);
            if (sts != -1)
                out[sts] = guessChars[index];
            else
                missedChars.add(guessChars[index]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Missed Character: " + missedChars.toString());
    return new String(out);
}
```

You can change `out[i] = '_';` to `out[i] = '-';`